# SimpleTransformers I am getting the same result using models RoBERTa and BERT

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, simpletransformers, roberta-language-model

I am new to simpletransformers and NLP in general, I am currently working on a project in which I need to collect a number of values based on a model that I train from the simple transformer's library. Currently, the models I am working with are BERT and RoBERTA, however after all is said and done I am getting the exact same values, for accuracy, precision, recall, and F1-Macro. I don't believe this to be true but I also haven't seen anything with a similar error, nor can I detect this error myself. I am using Google COLAB and I can link my code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nBLpDNLATQclNUqURxyQzs8VvStqyydX?usp=sharing). As for the data I am using a dataset from a professor that I have streamlined and that I can provide [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DchBijkKWoB7Tq_FG7kgrhMMVIiDmX_9/view?usp=share_link) for you. I would really appreciate the advice/assistance anyone can give!